# Running FFMPEGJS in a React Project

Tags: node.js, webpack, ffmpeg, create-react-app

I'm trying to get https://github.com/ffmpegjs/ffmpeg.js/ running in a  Create React App build project.

```
import {createWorker} from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
```

When I import the library the build fails with

```
./node_modules/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg/src/createWorker.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     logger,
|     progress,
|     ...options
|   } = resolvePaths({
|     ...defaultOptions,
```

I'm not sure how to handle this, or where the problem might be. Is this a Webpack issue?

Comment: It looks like you need an additional loader to build the js file `createWorker.js`.However, in general you avoid building the `/node_modules/`. Just to get a better idea of what is going on, could you share a bit of your webpack setup ? Or are you solely relying on Create React App ?

Comment: @beek, Did you solved the issue?